# SQL DateTime Adding Milliseconds

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables, one is populated by a simple insert statement and the other using a Table-Valued Parameter (due to the quantity of rows) and they both work from within an application.

The dates are passed from a .NET variable so they are both using the same value.

Both are `DATETIME NOT NULL`, however when the TVP enters the datetime it comes through like so:

```
2016-02-24 09:40:26.647
```

However in the `INSERT INTO` on the other table this comes through as:

```
2016-02-24 09:40:26.000
```

I need to join these values with another to link the data together, however the milliseconds is proving a problem.

---

My questions:

- How can I either remove the milliseconds from the TVP, or
- Can someone tell me why the TVP is inserting the full time where the `INSERT INTO` statement is only entering up to the 'second' in the other table?

Comment: which database are you using?, one simple approach can be ...casting the datetime field as date. That will remove the problem for milliseconds.

Comment: @AritraBhattacharya MS SQL 2008

Comment: @AritraBhattacharya Casting as just 'DATE' gets rid of the whole time, I want the time, just not the milliseconds

Comment: you can use this : CAST(FORMAT(@datetime,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') AS datetime) as well in case you need the time

Comment: You haven't detailed filling the TVP and `INSERT INTO` statement in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following:

```
DATEADD(ms, -(datepart(ms, RequestDT)), RequestDT)
```

Where RequestDT is my date, however I haven't found why the TVP and INSERT INTO both operate differently.

Answer (score 0):

Join tables over truncated dates.

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.*
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON (TO_CHAR(t1.datecolumn,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')=TO_CHAR(t2.datecolumn,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
CAST(FORMAT(RequestDT,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') AS datetime)
```